# Calling Flask route internally with requests

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I am trying to call one internal route through another Flask route. Essentially I want to develop a mini internal microservice.

```
try:
    import json
    import os
    import sys
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import app
    import requests
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

except Exception as e:
    print("Error : {} ".format(e))

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/call1', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def m_call1():
    return "call1"


@app.route('/call2', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def call2():
    res = requests.get('call1/')
    print(res.json())
    return "call2" + res.json()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that ? Why don't you simply call the method triggered when GET request happened on `/call1` ?

Comment: what error does it display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not suggested to do this but if you need to do so

You can try :
make a config.py and type in :

```
DOMAIN = ""
```

in your main file

```
from config import *
res = requests.get(f'{DOMAIN}/call1/')
```

Comment: i don't want to hard code the domain name is there any other alternatives?

Comment: make a config file :)

Comment: sure that made sense

Comment: If the answer was helpful kindly accept and upvote :)